# Connect resource server and spring-authorization-server on same server via opaque token

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

Good afternoon, colleagues.

I have spring-authorization-server (with configured opaque tokens) and several endpoints on the same server.
How is it possible to work with this endpoints via opaque tokens in native mode?

in one case I have next filter:

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1)
public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer = new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer();
    authorizationServerConfigurer.oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

    RequestMatcher endpointsMatcher = authorizationServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher();
    http
            .securityMatcher(endpointsMatcher)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(endpointsMatcher))
            .exceptionHandling(exceptions ->
                    exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::opaqueToken)
            .apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);
    return http.build();
}
```

But application doesn't start with error

```
Method authServerSecurityFilterChain in com.pet.project.AuthorizationServerConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.OpaqueTokenIntrospector' that could not be found.
```

So, we can somehow implement our own OpaqueTokenIntrospector, in which we don't make any request to ourself to /oauth2/token-info endpoint (e.g. OAuth2AuthorizationService.findByToken(String, OAuth2ParameterNames.ACCESS_TOKEN) and somehow else?)

Is it correct solution or does any other clean solution exist?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a cleaner solution and would not recommend doing so, though you could build your own custom `OpaqueTokenIntrospector`. Really, it's not intended for the authorization server to accept tokens it minted itself. If you really need to do it, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77337412/15835039) which configures the authz server to accept a JWT for some API endpoints.

You can configure different clients to use different types of tokens. So the `RegisteredClient` for your API endpoints should be configured to generate a JWT, and other (non-API) clients can have opaque tokens generated. See [OAuth2TokenGenerator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/core-model-components.html#oauth2-token-generator) in the docs for information on supported token formats. You can configure them on the `RegisteredClient` via `RegisteredClient.Builder#tokenSettings`.

Comment: Interesting proposal, thanks for your answer.
We are working only with one `RegisteredClient`, including for the authorization server, since it contains custom controllers for managing the client profile.

For now I created custom `OpaqueTokenIntrospector` and copied the most part of  `OAuth2TokenIntrospectionAuthenticationProvider`
(Yeah, I had to duplicate `OAuth2TokenIntrospection withActiveTokenClaims(OAuth2Authorization.Token<OAuth2Token> authorizedToken)` because it's private)