# How can I configure a Spring OAuth2 Auth Server to act both as an Auth and Resource Server, securing endpoints independently of session context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

I am currently working on an OAuth 2.0 login / user management system using [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security). Since I'm writing my own authorization server (based upon docs like [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html)) using the [`spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server/1.1.2) module, I am also implementing a user management / admin dashboard.

Naturally, the endpoints for the user management are on the auth server. So the auth server acts as authorization server and *(somewhat like a)* resource server. To authorize a user to use the admin dashboard, they will need to log-in of course, so first they are redirected to the auth servers `/authorize` endpoint which then redirects them to the login menu. The authorization code grant flow is then followed normally. But every step is being done on the same server *(i.e. authentication and accessing of the protected admin endpoints)*!

I am struggeling to configure our auth server to act as an auth server **AND** resource server because of the following issues:

The authorization server saves the `securityContext` to the session. The session ID ([`JSESSIONID`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/java-custom-cookie.html)) is then left in the users browser as a cookie. The problem is that when the user tries to access a secured endpoint on the auth server such as the `{...}/admin/users` endpoint, the cookie alone is enough to authorize them to make a request to that endpoint. This means that the entire authorization flow can be circumvented, when a bearer token should be requested first to access the protected endpoint. We would like the secured endpoints to be accessible **ONLY** with a bearer token and just a bearer token, not a session *(or a combination of both)*.

Here is a shortened version of the current security config:

```java
@Bean
@Order(1)
public CorsFilter corsFilter(CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource) {
    logger.info("Creating corsFilter bean");
    return new CorsFilter(corsConfigurationSource);
}


/**
 * Configures the authorization server endpoints.
 */
@Bean
@Order(2)
public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, RegisteredClientRepository clientRepository) throws Exception {

    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
            .registeredClientRepository(clientRepository) // autowired from ClientConfig.java
            .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

    http.exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
            .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                    new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                    new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
            )
    );

    http.oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
            .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
@Order(3)
public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.securityMatcher(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/**")));

    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
            authorize
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/register")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/recover")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/error/**")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/css/**")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/js/**")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/favicon.ico")).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated());

    http.oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
            .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

    // set custom login form
    http.formLogin(form -> {
        form.loginPage("/login");
        form.permitAll();
    });

    http.logout(conf -> {
        // default logout url
        conf.logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler());
    });

    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    http.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
@Order(4)
public SecurityFilterChain adminResourceFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // handle out custom endpoints in this filter chain
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
            authorize
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/**")).hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated());

    http.sessionManagement(conf -> conf.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

    http.oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
            .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    http.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

    return http.build();
}
```

**How to configure the authorization server so the admin endpoints are secured independently from the security context from the session?**

For disclosure purposes, I was debugging *a lot* and tried basically the whole [basics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html)! I also tried a few other things:

According to [Spring Security Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html), it's possible to set the `.sessionManagement` to STATELESS in the security config. I had hoped that this would fix the issue, but setting this in the resource server filter chain showed to cause another issue: With the session management flag set to STATELESS, the  login isn’t processed properly. After the POST request from the login form, instead of redirecting to the “redirect_url” from the `/authorize` request, the auth server redirects to “/”…? *I think this is because the auth server module relies on the security context saved to the session for some of its filters.*

I also had some issues with CORS and thought this might cause this.Considering that the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/integrations/cors.html) say:

> CORS must be processed before Spring Security because the pre-flight request will not contain any cookies (i.e. the JSESSIONID). If the request does not contain any cookies and Spring Security is first, the request will determine the user is not authenticated (since there are no cookies in the request) and reject it.

This would explain that thefront-end Vue.js application doesn't work properly, but not the debugging calls via Postman. Now I deactivated CORS to not deal with those issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following configuration sets up an extra filter chain for a set of admin endpoints, ordered to be between the auth server endpoints and the rest of the application (user authentication endpoints).

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
            .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http
            .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                    new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                    new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                )
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
            );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain adminSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
            .securityMatcher("/admin/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).hasAuthority("SCOPE_admin:read")
                .anyRequest().hasAuthority("SCOPE_admin:write")
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(3)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults);

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

You can simply create a `RegisteredClient` that provides `admin:read` and/or `admin:write` scopes. You should use a normal OAuth2 flow (such as `authorization_code` or `client_credentials`) to obtain access tokens with that scope. You don't want to attempt to customize the `adminSecurityFilterChain` to handle authenticating a user, that is already handled by the `defaultSecurityFilterChain`.

If you have a SPA (e.g. Vue.js), it becomes an OAuth2 Client to initiate a redirect for the authorization request (`GET /oauth2/authorize`), or better still should interact with a BFF using sessions and not worry about access tokens at all. Either way, the admin API is accessible via bearer tokens, though this pattern should used rarely. If building an authorization server product (i.e. keycloak-like) it might make sense, but in a microservices architecture I would suggest moving the admin endpoints to a separate microservice, which just keeps things simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Your resource server filter-chain should not contain anything about login and logout.

A resource server filter chain can be configured as "stateless" (without session) because the security context is built out of the access token (not from the session).

Login is an OAuth2 client concern, not a resource server one: this is the client sending requests to the resource server which acquires and stores tokens (resource server business is only token validation and access control).

Sessions (and protection against CSRF) are required on clients with `oauth2Login` (it is used during the authorization_code flow, to store tokens and to authorize incoming requests).

If your application was also hosting the client for your admin dashboard (Spring MVC controller with a template engine like Tymeleaf), then you could have defined a third filterchain for it (with sessions, CSRF protection and `oauth2Login`).

But as your dashboard UI seems to be a SPA (Vue application) it can't be a confidential client and login should be handled by a middleware:

- on your servers
- maintaining sessions for the frontend
- configured as OAuth2 confidential client with login
- storing tokens (Spring does it in session by default, which is just fine)
- protected against CSRF (with a cookie having http-only flag set to false in the case of a SPA)
- replacing session cookie with an Authorization header containing the access token in session before forwarding a request from the frontend to resource server(s)

This is frequently referred to as **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend pattern (BFF), and I wrote [a tutorial for that](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff).

Comment: this is the correct answer, because by implementing both issuer and resource server into one and the same means we are now not implementing _oauth2_ anymore. We have diverged from the specification and we are now in "custom security" territory and custom security is always bad practice.

Comment: @ch4mp I think your answer misses the mark here unfortunately. This question is about an AUTH SERVER. Not the client. Thats why there is login configuration in the security filter chain. The point is how to offer secured endpoints for an admin api on the auth server. Those endpoints would be considered "resources", thats why there is talk of configuring the server as a resource server and auth server

Comment: @Toerktumlare then how should the admin endpoints be secured instead? Obviously they have to be on the auth server, and most "out of the box" auth servers also have an admin api. So how should these endpoints be secured if not with a bearer token?

Comment: @HendrikHübner there is nothing that prevents you from in your auth server from creating multiple SecurityFilter setups and protecting some endpoints using basic auth, formLogin etc so i dont really see the problem here

Comment: @HendrikHübner either I don't understand what we are talking about or maybe you don't as much as you think. Read my answer again, and maybe follow the link I provided.

Comment: Just to clear up some confusion, the reason there is "login stuff" in the "defaultFilterChain" is to set the custom login page for the auth server as is described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#defining-required-components

Comment: There is nothing there stating that you should put login in a resource server filter-chain

Comment: @ch4mp I think you misunderstood. Above is an authentication server that would serve all of our front-ends. As an admin dashboard is required, the idea is to offer endpoints for a front-end for managing all admin-related duties (e.g. working on the auth server directly by adding a new blocked ip). So the auth server would serve both as a resource server (of some sort?) and an auth server. It would offer the basics of the authentication for our resource server, but also serves a few endpoints to manage admin/security/auth-related duties (deleting users, blacklisting, etc.)!

Comment: I perfectly understood that. What you seem not to understand is that **you don't authenticate to a resource server** (you just authorize with a Bearer token each request you send to it). Login has nothing to do in a resource server filter chain. Period. There is room for Form login in an authorization server filter-chain and for `oauth2Login` in a client filter-chain, but that's all. Just get some more [OAuth2 background](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials) (and probably read Spring official doc with more care)

Comment: yeah I think we've fixed that by now. We made a third filter chain with the admin endpoints. And setting it to stateless actually seems to have solved the problem. So while your answer didn't directly answer the question it did give us a clue. So thank you for that. I'm gonna post the updated filter chain as an answer later in case someone stumbles across this post in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Forced verification requires bearer token,in your defaultSecurityFilterChain config

```
   http.oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()).bearerTokenResolver(new CustomBearerTokenResolver() ));


public class CustomBearerTokenResolver implements BearerTokenResolver {

    private final BearerTokenResolver defaultBearerTokenResolver = new DefaultBearerTokenResolver();
    
    @Override
    public String resolve(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String resolveToken = defaultBearerTokenResolver.resolve(request);
        if(resolveToken == null){
            throw new RuntimeException("missing jwt token");
        }
        return resolveToken;
    }

}
```